# text based search api for skobbler web integrators

Tags: leaflet, skmaps

I am using a skobbler map web API with leafletjs, and I want to implement the search feature (like Google maps Geocoding API), given a name of the city or address of a place it should return approximate or exact geocode (lat, lng). is there such an API exist with skobbler or I have to use 3rd party api and feed data to skobbler?

I am trying to implement some feature of maps.skobbler.com but not all of them just a text search is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Currently skobbler/Telenav does not offer an online geocoding service on the standard plan.

On mobile you can access this functionality once you download the map data as an on-board package but on mobile you will need to integrate (delegate to) another geocoding service.